# Sending Sign-up link to Gmail in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to send the signup  link to Gmail account when User Registered for the First time, I mean for checking the Authenticity of the User Email address. I have achieve this but my problem is that user is not getting any link and message body also. If I am defining this two in my function its giving me error. This is My function which gives me Following Error:

> "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HttpContext.get'" and syntax error
>   for message.body="".

What should I do for this?

```
public class EmailManager
{
    private const string EmailFrom = "noreplay@gmail.com";
    public static void SendConfirmationEmail(string userName)
    {
        var user = Membership.GetUser(userName.ToString());
        var confirmationGuid = user.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
        //var verifyUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart
        //   (UriPartial.Authority) + "/Account/Verify/" + confirmationGuid;

        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            using (var message = new MailMessage(EmailFrom, user.Email))
            {
                message.Subject = "Please Verify your Account";
//              message.Body = "To verify your account, please click the following link:"
//+ "<a href=\"" + verifyUrl + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + verifyUrl + "
//+"</a></p><div>Best regards,</div><div>Someone</div><p>Do not forward "
//+"this email. The verify link is private.</p></body></html>";

                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Send(message);
            };
        };
    }
}
```

Please help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

You mean your `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart` throws an error. That is correct, because you're in the class `EmailManager`, while you actually mean to access the Controller's context.

So change your signature:

```
SendConfirmationEmail(string userName, string verifyUrl)
{

}
```

And pass it from the controller:

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        [...]

        var verifyUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart;
        var mailManager = new MailManager();

        mailManager.SendConfirmationEmail("TestUser", verifyUrl);

        [...]
    }
}
```